# PHP artisan serve error - failed to listen on 127.0.0

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, window

I was writing in terminal to install Laravel on my PC but this is what I’m getting. Is that has to do something with my IP address? I’ve downloaded Xampserver to fix this but still nope.

Comment: what is the actual command that you've ran?

Comment: Is it programming question. If not please clear your question a bit more

Comment: command - Failed to listen on 127. 0.0.1:8000 (reason: an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing `artisan` serve `port` using this command:**

```
php artisan serve --port=4546
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things

1. change a port
2. Stop applications which runs on port 80(Skype probably )

---

**Changing  port**

```
php artisan serve --port=8085
```

**Stop Skype**

```
Skype>Tools>Options>Advanced>Connection.
```

Untick/Uncheck **Use port 80 and 443 as an alternatives for incoming connections**

click <kbd>Save</kbd>

Comment: did you check this ??